# Third party Vue Component throwing unexpected token error when importing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Trying to include a third party vue component called vue-product-carousel through NPM using laravel-elixir-vueify.

package.json contains:

```
"laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
"laravel-elixir-vueify": "^1.0.6",
"vue": "^1.0.26",
"vue-product-carousel": "^0.1.3"
```

Node and NPM:

```
NPM 3.8.6
NODE 5.12.0
```

Components I write are vuefied just fine and it works great. When I try to incldue vue-product-carosuel it throws this error:

```
/home/vagrant/Code/core-ds/node_modules/vue-product-carousel/src/carousel.vue:1
<template>
^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

Component is being required like so:

```
carousel: require('vue-product-carousel')
```

and the element:

```
<carousel :images="media"></carousel>  //media is an array of images
```

Is it possible I'm missing something with my build?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is some configuration excluding files from inside `node_modules` to be parsed by `vueify`.

In this case, the `require` is treating "carousel.vue" as a JavaScript file.